# FileNotFoundException when trying to access ZipFile in jar

Tags: java, file, jar, zip

I want to open a ZipFile in Java, that is in the .jar after exporting the project from eclipse. This is the code I have written:

```
String modpath = "/ModByDNSYeti.zip";
URL url = this.getClass().getResource(modpath);

ZipFile newTextures = new ZipFile(url.toString());
```

If I execute the jar, I get a

> FileNotFoundException: file:"path"

where "path" is the exact path where the ZipFile is. It is there. I checked it a hundered times by now, but I can not figure out what to do. I get the same error when starting the programm from Eclipse. Google did not get me anywhere, either.

Regards
DNSYeti

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a Resource as a File, which will not work - that is why you are getting the FileNotFound exception. What you can do is grab the resource as a stream and use it to create a ZipInputStream:

```
ZipInputStream zipInStream = new ZipInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(modpath));
```

You can then use the ZipInputStream to read the ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but I have a followup question:

Comment: In the rest of the method, two ZipFiles are merged to one ZipOutputStream. I could simply replace one of the ZipFiles with the ZipInputStream but this would cause another problem: I want the ZipInputStream to override any Entrys that have been put into the ZipOutputStream by the ZipFile. Since I can not actually delete any Items in an ZipOutputStream, I have to check if the overwriting ZipFile contains the file and if it does, not let the ZipFile that is beeing overwritten place it as Entry into the stream. That does not work when the overwriting File is a ZipInputStream.

Comment: If you need random access to the zip the ZipInputStream is indeed not very helpful. In that case you might want to consider not putting .zip files into the .jar file but instead shipping them alongside the .jar itself. Alternatively you could basically copy the .zips from your .jar to a temporary file and then use the `ZipFile(String)` for random access.